# Doesnt work my text input layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-textinputlayout

I'm a beginner in Android :( I'm using a text input layout but I cant catch any value of them! This is my code. For now I want to print the value "usuario" just to check if it has any value. I'm using Butterknife btw D:

```
public class IngresoFragment extends Fragment {

@Bind(R.id.tilUsuario) TextInputLayout mTilUsuario;
@Bind(R.id.tilPassword) TextInputLayout mTilPassword;
@Bind(R.id.btnIngresar) Button btnIngresar;
@Bind(R.id.tviLibre) TextView tviLibre;

public IngresoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ingreso, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    app();
}

void app(){

    mTilUsuario.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.usuario));
    mTilPassword.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.password));
    events();
}

void events(){
    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String usuario = mTilUsuario.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mTilPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), usuario, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `EditText` instead of `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

in Android text input box is define as EditText just chenge TextInputLayout to EditText